# AngularJs - $location.path not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have couple of questions regarding `$location.path(/helpmeunderstand)` . I have a `login()` method and ones the credentials are successful i want to navigate `$location.path(/login/:username)`, but it does not show the name of the user who is logged in instead it just shows, `/login/:username`.

Please note i am doing this inside of the `$scope.function`, but does not work.

```
$scope.isValidUser = function() {
            gitHubApiFactory.getUserName($scope.gitUserName)
                .success(function (user) {
                    $scope.gitUser = user;
                    $scope.loaded = true;
                    $location.path( "/login/{{user.login}}" );
                    console.log(user);

                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.userNotFound = true;
                    $log.log(data.error + ' ' + status);
                });
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Show us some code ....

Comment: Thanks, code is now in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use the {{}} bracket syntax that way.  It only works for HTML templates and bindings.

Try this:

```
$scope.isValidUser = function() {
            gitHubApiFactory.getUserName($scope.gitUserName)
                .success(function (user) {
                    $scope.gitUser = user;
                    $scope.loaded = true;
                    $location.path( "/login/" + user.login);
                    console.log(user);

                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.userNotFound = true;
                    $log.log(data.error + ' ' + status);
                });
```

Comment: Thank you sir :) saved me lot of time. sorry very new to angularjs